# jQuery Validate with custom web components

Tags: jquery-validate, web-component

With the addition of form associated web components, we are now able to write custom web components that act as a form item when placed inside a form. I am wondering if it is possible to use jQuery Validate with a form associated custom web component?

From what I can tell looking through the code it appears to be hard-coded to use the standard HTML form inputs and there doesn't appear to be a way around this without modifying the jQuery validate code, but wanted to be sure that there weren't any "hacks" to get around that, or if someone has already made the modifications out there somewhere.

I also realize that I could potentially hook into the native form validation API, but this is for a form that is already using jQuery validate and I don't really want to have to convert it over to the native API.

Comment: *"hard-coded to use the standard HTML form inputs and there doesn't appear to be a way around this without modifying the jQuery validate code"* - yes, correct.  I've answered thousands of jQuery Validate questions and know of nothing already made that satisfies your request.